# Undefined method save for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo el siguiente código:

orders_controller.rb:

```
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.total_without_discounts = 0
    @order.total_with_discounts = 0
    @cart.items.each do |item|
        orderProduct = OrderProduct.new
        orderProduct.count = item.count 
        orderProduct.product = item.product 
        orderProduct.discount = calculate_discounts(item)
        @order.total_with_discounts += item.total - (orderProduct.discount * item.count)
        @order.total_without_discounts += item.total
        @order.order_products << orderProduct
    end

    
end

def create
    if(@order.save)
        redirect_to root_path,notice: "Order succesfully loaded, thank you for choosing us."
    else
        redirect_to root_path,notice: "Ooops! Something went wrong, try again in a few seconds."
    end
end
```

La parte del new está funcionando ya que en la vista los datos se ven correctamente.

orders new_view :

```
... 
<div class="mt-6">
        <%= link_to orders_path,data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :create,params: @order} , do %>
          Confirm
        <% end %>
      </div>
...
```

Cuando clickeo en confirmar no sucede nada en el navegador y la consola de rails devuelve:

```
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:4:in `<class:OrdersController>'
byebuy-web-1  |   Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
byebuy-web-1  |   ↳ app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:5:in `<class:OrdersController>'
byebuy-web-1  | Processing by OrdersController#create as */*
byebuy-web-1  |   Parameters: {"total_with_discounts"=>"176850", "total_without_discounts"=>"258900"}
byebuy-web-1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 54ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1458)
byebuy-web-1  |
byebuy-web-1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass):
byebuy-web-1  | app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:30:in `create'
```

En la base de datos hay una tabla Products, otra Orders y otra OrderProducts.
Las asociaciones serían:
Product has many OrderProducts /
Order has many OrderProducts /
OrderProducts belongs to Order and Products

¿Qué podría estar fallando? Porque estoy enviándole la instancia @order a orders_controller, pero no lo está recibiendo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder llamar a `@order.save`, primero debes inicializar esa variable `@order`. Si estás usando strong parameters (lo desconozco, ya que no compartiste esa parte del código), lo normal es que sea con algo como:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
```

o en su defecto con:

```
@order = Order.new(params[:order])
```

Luego de eso ya tendrás una instancia de `Order` la cual puedas guardar.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de utilizar la instancia inicializada en el metodo new dentro de create?

Comment: Pero la inicialización es distinta para `new` (`Order.new`) y para `create` (`Order.new(order_params)`), no veo el por qué querrías usarla nuevamente. El resto del código de `new` quizás podría ser movido a un método aparte y llamarlo desde ambos actions, pero se me hace que para `create` toda esa información ya debería venir desde `order_params`. Si no es el caso, quizás podría valer la pena ese refactoring.

Comment: La idea era esa en un principio pero no logro enviar la order como parametro. Lo que estaba haciendo era desde la vista `link_to orders_path,data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :create,params: { :order => @order}}` . Y luego en el metodo create del controlador  `@order = Order.new(params[:order]) `.

Comment: ¿Eso significa que no estás enviando o modificando información desde un formulario en `new`? ¿La orden debería siempre crearse al presionar el link de `Confirm` e iniciarse tal cual con los valores fijados en el action `new`? Lo que estás haciendo de mandar una estructura tan compleja como `@order` a través de un link no es posible. Deberías mandar los campos desde un formulario o que todas las órdenes creadas tengan los mismos valores a lo que definiste en el `new`.